# Scrolltop doesn't stay faded out, and it does't reverse when scrolling up

Tags: javascript, html, fadeout, scrolltop

I am very new to javascript.

I need a nav bar at the top to disappear and get replace by a smaller one at a certain scrolltop period. Once I reach a certain scroll top number I need the function to be executed and stay "faded-out" until you scroll back up to the same scroll top number.
I have been experimenting with this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).scroll(function () {
if ($(document).scrollTop() > 250 ) {
    $('#moving_nav').removeClass('tiny');
    $('.subhead, .navbar-brand').fadeIn(0.1);

} else {
    $('#moving_nav').addClass('tiny');
    $('.subhead, .navbar-brand').fadeOut(0.1);
}
});
</script>
```

The problem I have right now its doing  alot of funky things. At 250 it work ok, but is unable to do the reverse when scrolling up and when I change the number, at some point while scrolling down it goes back to its original state.

Please let me know how my code looks? Is there a more accurate/ correct way to go about this?

Thank you so much!

http://jsfiddle.net/NotJavascriptFriendly/F38As/

Comment: I'll encourage you to make a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) ;)

Comment: It looks really messy..http://jsfiddle.net/NotJavascriptFriendly/F38As/ I am using boostrap.

Comment: Ok, here's a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/F38As/2/). Is that what you want?